# Tomcat + JPA + MySQL : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jpa, entitymanager

as part of a school project, I must connect a java REST API to a MySql database.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to instantiate the EntityManagerFactory.
I've already tried to find the solution online, but I couldn't fix my issues.

I have several classes that will need to be stored in the datacase, and I've used annotations to describe them (basically @Entity annotations, @ManyToOne and others, and of course @Id and @GeneratedValue

My custom EntityManager :

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class NatagoraEntityManager {
    private EntityManager manager;
    public NatagoraEntityManager(){
        EntityManagerFactory factory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");
        manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

My RestController :

```
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {

    private NatagoraEntityManager manager;
    public HelloWorld(){
        //Without this line it works fine
        manager = new NatagoraEntityManager();
    }


    // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
    @GET
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media type "text/plain"
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        // Return some cliched textual content
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">
        <properties>

            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://111.111.111.111:3306/bdname/"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="login"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="password"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Tool=INFO"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>JAXRS-Example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAXRS-Example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>0.99</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>[1.0.2,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-persistence-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>[1.0.1,)</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And finally, here is the errors I receive :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at DAL.NatagoraEntityManager.<init>(NatagoraEntityManager.java:10)
    at main.java.HelloWorld.<init>(HelloWorld.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor._construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:245)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.spi.component.ResourceComponentConstructor.construct(ResourceComponentConstructor.java:233)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$PerRequest._getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.resource.PerRequestFactory$AbstractPerRequest.getInstance(PerRequestFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationContext.getResource(WebApplicationContext.java:239)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1339)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 43 more
```

If you find an answer somewhere, I'll be grateful, as I'm stuck since several hours on this problem.
If you need more informations, I'll be happy to tell you what you need.

Thank you !

EDIT : 
Here is a part of my project.iml file where I choose the JPA provider :

```
<facet type="jpa" name="JPA">
      <configuration>
        <setting name="validation-enabled" value="true" />
        <setting name="provider-name" value="OpenJPA" />
        <datasource-mapping />
        <deploymentDescriptor name="persistence.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
```

EDIT2 : changed the pom.xml

EDIT3 : Here are the jars included in my WAR file :
[image: First part of the libraries]
[image: Second part of the libraries]

Comment: You put "javax.persistence" jar (a very old version of it, v1.0.2! Current JPA standard is v2.2) in the CLASSPATH, but don't see an actual JPA provider there. Which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: Is OpenJPA the answer you're looking for ? I'll edit my answer to add this element

Comment: OpenJPA is a JPA provider. And have you put it in the CLASSPATH? because its not in your `pom.xml`. And if you are using `javax.persistence` v1.0.2 then you would need a very old version of OpenJPA. Also, what relevance does your `pom.xml` have relative to Tomcat? are you putting those jars into Tomcat? because if you aren't then you will fail

Comment: I changed my pom.xml to reflet your comment. But I don't get what you're saying about Tomcat, so I'll look into it. Is there a way to send the jars automatically when deploying ?

Comment: Your `pom.xml` will normally build a jar or war file. You then deploy that (to Tomcat). Either your war file needs to include the JPA provider and the javax.persistence, OR you need to manually put those jars into Tomcat.

Comment: I added the libraries that are included in the war. I checked and found both the persistence and the jpa provider in the list. So i'd suppose that tomcat does have the libraries needed ?

Comment: OpenJPA v2.4.2 requires JPA v2.0. You have this "geronimo-jpa_2.0...", but you also have "javax.persistence" v1.0.2 ... so they conflict. Remove the JPA 1.0.2 version from the war

Comment: I removed it from the war, but the problem persist. I've restarted the computer and rebuild the project. I've also tried by removing javax.persistence from the pom.xml file, but it didn't change anything. I checked the logs : the war is deployed to the server, and I restart tomcat before each deployement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a lot of changes to make this project work.

Here is my pom.xml now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>JAXRS-Example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JAXRS-Example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>0.99</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.44</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdname"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="login"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I also had to change the whole structure of my project, because I had several packages not included in main.java. Now, everything is organized in this package and not outside.